# Can you set a variable name equal to another variable's value?

Tags: javascript

I am interested in knowing if its even possible.

One example is the variable already exists.

```
foo = 1;
var bar = 'foo';

if('foo' == 1)?
```

Is there a way to do that.

Is there a way to say something like `bar == foo.variablename`

Comment: If you create the variable, you should know its name anyway. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
s="unicorn"
eval("var " + s + " = 'test'")
alert(unicorn)
```

but from the text in your question it kind of sounds like you want to check if a variable exists and that is also possible

```
if (typeof variable == "undefined") alert("It's not defined!");
```

Answer (score 1):

No to variables, Yes to properties. Since variables are properties:

```
javascript:var foo='bar';this[foo]='baz';alert(bar)
```

Comment: It seems like print variable name should be a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I didn't get what's your concrete purpose, but with function `eval` you should be able to perform the desired operation.